# x86 - swap contents of 2 registers

Tags: assembly, x86

I'd like to compare 2 16-bit unsigned registers and swap their contents if the first one is greater. for example, if `ax` contains 00FF and `bx` contains FFFF, I'd like to swap their contents.  Is there a command that does this or a simple procedure used for swapping?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no single instruction that does this.  Just do `cmp` `jb` `xchg`

Comment: You can also use the `cmovCC` instructions.

Comment: Aaron, there is an answer to your question, check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is "x86 - swap contents of 2 registers". You can use `XCHG` instruction, example :

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
.code
  mov  ax, @data
  mov  ds, ax

  mov  ax, 0ffffh
  mov  bx, 0ffh

  cmp  ax, bx
  ja   swap           ;IF AX > BX...
  jmp  continue

swap:  
  xchg ax, bx         ;◄■■■ AX BECOMES 0FFH, BX BECOMES 0FFFFH.

continue:  

  mov  ax, 4c00h
  int  21h
```

Comment: That may be the title, but the question itself is clear (including the OP giving an example): _I'd like to compare 2 16-bit unsigned registers and swap their contents if the first one is greater_

Comment: @MichaelPetch, that's easy to fix.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid a jump in case ax already holds the largest value (and you know that most of the time it will, and you want to avoid jump induced instruction pipeline refills that might occur depending on the cpu implementation ...), or you just want to save a byte (xchg ax,bx is a single byte op code):

```
    cmp  ax, bx
    jb   bx_is_bigger
    xchg ax, bx
bx_is_bigger:
    xchg ax, bx
```

Comment: Better: `jnb` to skip the `xchg`, so `xchg` runs 0 or 1 times, rather than 2 or 1 times.  If you're optimizing for speed, it's better to avoid needing to actually swap.  e.g. before you have them in `ax` and `bx`, after maybe you have them in `dx` and `ax`, so you can it by jumping over two `mov` instructions.  (`xchg` decodes to 3 uops, so it costs about the same as 3 `mov` instructions on modern CPUs).  It's not usually worth using, outside of [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77270/greatest-common-divisor/77364#77364) or other purely code-size situations.